# I am looking for an explanation of inference of results from weighted regression for a ratio of two continous variables.

Tags: regression, inference, weighted-regression, ratio

I am performing a weighted regression for a ratio $R = \frac{Y}{X}$ using $X$ as weights. Y and X are normal and they are not independent. Is it valid to use $X$ as weights? What is the interpretation of $\hat{R}$ from the regression? Can someone point me to the a literature reference?

Comment: Are you dividing $Y$ by $X$ *and* using $X$ as a weight, or is the division by $X$  how the weighting is being applied?

Comment: This is the regression: $R = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot I$ where $R = \frac{Y}{X}$ and use denominator $X$ as weights.